# Excel: Classifiying data based on a bin system

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I'm working with excel 2010 on windows, am a novice excel user but I can program, so you are welcome to throw VBA at me.
I have a series of cells where a user can enter a number and another cell needs to display a classification based on the interval that number lies in.

e.g:

```
0%:     -> nothing
01-20%: -> not a lot
21-50%  -> below average

etc...
```

This is necessary for a number of different formats (integers, floats). What is the most elegant way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to have a look-up table with the bin data somewhere in your workbook. You can then use a `VLOOKUP` function to classify your input by comparing it to the table.

[image]

On this sample data, with look-up table located at `E3:F8` and user input located at `B1`, you would use the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$E$3:$F$8,2,TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state this HAD to be in VBA. I believe it is easier to accomplish with a formula rather than try to trigger VBA from user input.

So, here is a way to use nested `IF` with the `AND` statement to accomplish what you described. In this case, the value is entered in `A1` and the classification is displayed in `B1`.

Place this formula in `B1`.

```
=IF(AND(A1>0.7,A1<=1),"above average",IF(AND(A1>0.5,A1<=0.7),"average",IF(AND(A1>0.2,A1<=0.5),"below average",IF(AND(A1>0.01,A1<=0.2),"not a lot", ""))))
```

You may need to adjust things to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer using VBA and then customize and over-complicate as you like haha:

```
Function MyFunction(inputvalue As Double)

  Select Case inputvalue

    Case Is = 0:
    MyFunction = "nothing"
    Case Is <= 0.2:
    MyFunction = "not a lot"
    Case Is <= 0.5:
    MyFunction = "below average":
    Case Is > 0.5:
    MyFunction = "above average"

  End Select

End Function
```